# Handle hard-coded client side request in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im using an external client side (JS) library which makes a post back to a specific URL that I don’t have in my asp.net MVC application. This 404’s but I want to better handle this by just returning a 200 (or some other result that isn’t deemed an error). I can’t get the client side library changed and changing it myself isn’t an option.

The library causes a post back to the server to

> /config/options

on every page load. I know I could create an MVC ConfigController and in an Options action return an EmptyResult, but wondered if there was a more succinct or elegant way to handle this? Perhaps in routing or some other mechanism?

Any suggestions most welcome

Comment: tbh, not sure you'll be able to get more *succinct* than `return EmptyResult;`.   You could try an `ActionFilter` applied at the controller level with a route to one of the existing actions (as I understand it, there needs to be an action for the action filter to apply to (indirectly via the controller)) then check if it's /config/options - but it's starting to get messy and brittle (easy to break).  Action filter will also apply after the route, so there needs to be a route (eg the default route).

Comment: If you already have another, existing action that can be used, then you could use a route to point to that action - is this an option?

Answer (score 0):

Use a specific "hard coded" route in your routeMaps on the mvc side:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "UselessConfigOption",
       "config/options",
       new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "MyAction"});
```

Then, you can return whatever you'd like from MyCtrlController.MyAction.

If you know, in advance, that this call is being made within jquery (an .Ajax call), then you may be able to intercept on the client side instead.